# Python multiprocessing queue very slow

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am using multiprocessing queue to process my records.

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

def produce(i, item):
    data = process(i, item)
    queue.put(data)

def process(item):
    data = do_processing(item)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = load_records()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
        print('produce items')
        for i, item in ennumerate(records.items()):
            executor.submit(produce, i, item)

    print('queue size:{}'.format(queue.qsize()))
    while not queue.empty():
        save(queue.get())
```

The queue initially works quite fast. But as the queue grows the becomes very slow.

As per other SO answers, I have also tried with `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` with no luck.

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: You need to be pulling items off the queue while you're still submitting, so the queue doesn't grow too big. You can do this with a thread, or in this case I would say use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` (which punts submitting tasks and retrieving results to a thread for you). IMAO, there's no situation where `concurrent.futures` has a better offering than just `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: @Aaron if I use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` how to get `i`?

Comment: enumerate returns an iterator you can call map or imap with...

Comment: @Aaron can you please elaborate on an answer? Would really appreciate that.

Comment: I should also point out that using `while not queue.empty()` could miss results if you have a task that takes a little while to run, and you manage to clear the queue before it's done processing. It's usually best to know exactly how many items you ought to `get` from the queue, or to send some sort of sentinel from the worker to indicate that no more data will be coming.

Comment: @Aaron that is not true. `with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor` runs within a context and would ensure that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237197/discussion-between-aaron-and-exploring).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you never pull data off the queue until all the jobs have been submitted, which could take a significant amount of time, allowing quite a buffer to fill up.

Python's `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` sends inputs to the workers using a thread that only holds the iterator (read up on the efficiency of iterators/generators), while another thread collects outputs as they're done, and presents them to the output iterator so they can be consumed as they're created so you never have to buffer a large amount of items (as long as you read them faster than they're produced).

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def produce(args):
    i, item = args #unpack tuple returned by enumerate
    data = process(i, item)
    return data

def process(i, item): #added "i" missing from original post
    data = do_processing(i, item) #do something with "i"?
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = load_records()

    with Pool() as pool:
        print('produce items')
        for result in pool.imap(produce, enumerate(records.items())):
            save(result)
```

Comment: I cant directly save result as all of them are writing to the same file.

Comment: @Exploring in this example, `save` is being called only in the main process, so there's no overlapping access to the file. There is no conflict here. Just because it is inside the `with` context doesn't mean it's happening in parallel. Only the process of `map`ing over the `produce` function is happening in parallel.

Comment: So `pool.imap(produce, enumerate(records.items()))` will block until all the processes completes. This understanding is correct?

Comment: @Exploring Iterating over the results in the `for` loop will block until the "next" result is available, so yes all tasks will be completed.